# PHP sqlite3 Table not found

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

hi so I'm trying to add things to my database to check if it works but even though I've created the tables and have added things to the genres table it wont add to the products able[image]

[image]
the top shows the error im having whiles the bottom shows all available tables in the datebase

```
Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->double('price');
        $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('genres_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('genres_id')->references('id')->on('genres')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

this is the code for the database and all its columns needed.

Any help solving this would be very appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The table is called `product` but in your query you are using `products` you have an extra `s`

Comment: the query says im using products but im typing
$product = new App\product

at no point is `products` mentioned in code

Comment: What framework / code are you using? Have a look in your product class - it looks like it is enforcing a naming convention so you may have to rename your table to products

Comment: laravel and php i checked everything ive only ever used product i havent put an extra s anywhere in my whole project

Comment: See the docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions ' The "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified' . In your product class you could add the protected variable:  

protected $table = 'product';